# angularjs ng-style: background-image isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I'm trying to apply a background image to a div by using the angular `ng-style` ( I tried a custom directive before with the same behaviour ), but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<nav
    class="navigation-grid-container"
    data-ng-class="{ bigger: isNavActive == true }"
    data-ng-controller="NavigationCtrl"
    data-ng-mouseenter="isNavActive = true; $parent.isNavActive = true"
    data-ng-mouseleave="isNavActive = false; $parent.isNavActive = false"
    data-ng-show="$parent.navInvisible == false"
    data-ng-animate="'fade'"
    ng-cloak>

    <ul class="navigation-container unstyled clearfix">
        <li
            class="navigation-item-container"
            data-ng-repeat="(key, item) in navigation"
            data-ng-class="{ small: $parent.isNavActive, big: isActive == true }"
            data-ng-mouseenter="isActive = true; isInactive= false"
            data-ng-mouseleave="isActive = false; isInactive= true">

            <div data-ng-switch on="item.id">

                <div class="navigation-item-default" data-ng-switch-when="scandinavia">
                    <a class="navigation-item-overlay" data-ng-href="{{item.id}}">
                        <div class="navigation-item-teaser">
                            <span class="navigation-item-teaser-text" data-ng-class="{ small: isScandinavia }">{{item.teaser}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <span class="navigation-item-background" data-ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'public/img/products/{{item.id}}/detail/wide/{{item.images.detail.wide[0]}}' }"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation-item-last" data-ng-switch-when="static">
                    <div class="navigation-item-overlay">
                        <div class="navigation-item-teaser">
                            <span class="navigation-item-teaser-text">
                                <img data-ng-src="{{item.teaser}}">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="navigation-item-background">
                        <img class="logo" data-ng-src="{{item.images.logo}}">
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation-item-default" data-ng-switch-default>
                    <a class="navigation-item-overlay" data-ng-href="{{item.id}}">
                        <div class="navigation-item-teaser">
                            <span class="navigation-item-teaser-text">{{item.teaser}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <span class="navigation-item-background" data-ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'public/img/products/{{item.id}}/detail/wide/{{item.images.detail.wide[0]}}' }"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Though, if I do try a background color, it seems to be working fine. I tried a remote source and a local source too `http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/sports/`, neither worked.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Correct syntax for `background-image` is:

```
background-image: url("path_to_image");
```

Correct syntax for ng-style is:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png)'}">
```

Comment: btw, how do I render something like: `{{products.products[currenRoute].desc}}`; in html ?

Comment: I suppose `currentRoute` is a product ID from the route? If that's the case then $routeParams service, if you inject it into your controller, will hold the reference to your id (`$scope.productId = $routeParams.id`), given that your route is defined as '/products/:id'. But you might want to open a new question for that.

Comment: Something like that, but I already have access to `currenRoute`. It's a string, so I have a list of products: http://snippi.com/s/rznpfvo ; and my `currentRoute` it's a string which matches one of the id's in the list of products. And since I cannot do `{{products.products.currenRoute.desc}}` I have to find another way ...

Comment: Using, for example [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere), in your controller: `$scope.product = _($scope.products).findWhere({id: $scope.currentRoute})`, and than in your view: `<span>{{product.title}}</span>`. But let's not use comments as a chat. Post a new question.

Answer (score 190):

It is possible to parse dynamic values in a couple of way.

**Interpolation with double-curly braces:**

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{myBackgroundUrl}})'}"
```

**String concatenation:**

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + myBackgroundUrl + ')'}"
```

**ES6 template literals:**

```
ng-style="{'background-image': `url(${myBackgroundUrl})`}"
```

Comment: This actually is the best answer (or at least to my problem...)

Comment: Also you can write an expression using curly braces: `data-ng-style="{'background-image':'url(img/products/{{product.img}})'}"`

Comment: Beware, if you're using incorrect syntax (like escaped single-quotes inside `url()`) the browser may reject the value and not set it.

Comment: your option was not working for me.  but the 2nd option DID work. Thanks

Comment: first is not working. second work. the best answer thanks

Answer (score 15):

IF you have data you're waiting for the server to return (item.id) and have a construct like this:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://www.myImageplusitsid/{{item.id}})'}"
```

Make sure you add something like `ng-if="item.id"`

Otherwise you'll either have two requests or one faulty.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are struggling to get this working with IE11

**HTML**

```
<div ng-style="getBackgroundStyle(imagepath)"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getBackgroundStyle = function(imagepath){
    return {
        'background-image':'url(' + imagepath + ')'
    }
}
```

Comment: You just saved my life right now thank you.. I have spent hours trying to figure out why my ng-style was not showing in IE 11.  I still don't understand why but this worked!

Comment: Was the only thing that worked in chromium as well (ubuntu) all other examples or "the official way" seems to be ignored. The style is changed but have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, curly braces are not required.

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(../../../app/img/notification/'+notification.icon+'.png)'}"
```

notification.icon here is scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

> If we have a dynamic value that needs to go in a css background or
>   background-image attribute, it can be just a bit more tricky to
>   specify.
>
> Let’s say we have a getImage() function in our controller. This
>   function returns a string formatted similar to this:
>   url(icons/pen.png). If we do, the ngStyle declaration is specified the
>   exact same way as before:

```
ng-style="{ 'background-image': getImage() }"
```

---

> Make sure to put quotes around the background-image key name.
>   Remember, this must be formatted as a valid Javascript object key.

Comment: Whats the source of the citation?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records you can also define your object in the controller like this:

```
this.styleDiv = {color: '', backgroundColor:'', backgroundImage : '' };
```

and then you can define a function to change the property of the object directly:

```
this.changeBackgroundImage = function (){
        this.styleDiv.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.backgroundImage+')';
    }
```

Doing it in that way you can modify dinamicaly your style.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is changed for Angular 2 and above:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(path)'}"
```