# angularjs ng-style doesn't work on background

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

On another thread I got the information that the background can be set dynamically by using mg-style. Unfortunately I can't get it work.

syntax like this:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png)'}"
```

I have a fiddle for testing: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/WUe2P/31/)

fiddle:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right item-avatar defaultItem" data-ng-repeat="item in items " data-ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{item.url}})'}">
```

The background-image of the ion-item should be set to the mg-style element.

Comment: It is working as it should: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to set a background-image dynamically. The background isn't applied to the background of the list-element .. see question

Comment: The background css is applied correctly. That's an ionic issue. It has nothing to do with `ngStyle`. The list item has styles defined in css files supplied by ionic framework doesn't show up background for `ion-item` in `ion-list`. It just applies background-color. The background image is underneath. you can see it if you play around with the div in developer tools

Comment: Isn't there a workarround for that ... is it possible to set the image by javascript manually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252546/angularjs-ng-style-background-image-isnt-working

Answer (score 0):

Seen elsewhere ([Ionic Forums - credit to maxx0r](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ng-style-background-image-not-being-applied-on-initial-load/17764/2)) : don't use ng-style but style instead. That has worked for me.
So your example should change as follows:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right item-avatar defaultItem" data-ng-repeat="item in items " style="background-image:url({{item.url}})">
```

HTH, best regards.

Comment: you will get invalid urls before item.url is resolved (like %7b%7bitem.url%7d%7d)

Comment: Have you tested or are you just "supposing"? I repeat: I got it working that way. So maybe your failure is elsewhere.

Comment: have tested, have sauce: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.