# angular, background image and background position

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm struggling to add additional `background` styles using `ng-style`. The idea of what I am trying to do is make a grid of speakers using `ng-repeat`, each grid element having it's own image of a speaker. This is fine, except that I want the images to be a `background`, and while I can successfully get the image to reflect I can't add the css for `background-position` & `background-size`. The basics of what I am doing is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252546/angularjs-ng-style-background-image-isnt-working), but the issue is I've tried using inline styles unsuccessfully:

**CODE:**

```
<div class="grid" ng-repeat="speaker in home.speakers">
   <div class="grid-image" ng-style="{'background':'url({{speaker.img}})' 'center center' '/' 'cover'}"></div>
   <span class="caption"><h3>{{speaker.name}}</h3></span>
</div>
```

I've played with the single quotes every imaginable way, but still get the console error that it has no idea what I am trying to do. I've also tried just setting `background size` and `background position` in a separate class, but this doesn't work because the image isn't declared with it. I really am at a loss here, though I would assume I wouldn't be the first to try this, I'm just finding nothing helpful on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you are using `background-image` and applying the [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) for `background`, so here:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{speaker.img}})' 'center center' '/' 'cover'}">
```

change to:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{speaker.img}})', 'background-position': 'center center', 'background-size': 'cover'}">
```

Comment: Yep I agree. Here an example: [Example](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/MKPMaO?editors=1011)

Comment: You're right about the `background-image`, I accidentally put that in the question, the code you gave me worked like a charm, but is there a way to get shorthand to work, or do I have to define each style as you did in your answer? Also, do you know why I can't use a class that defines position and size and declare JUST the image with ng-style?

Comment: I'm no expert in AngularJS, but take a look at [this](http://jaketrent.com/post/ngstyle-background/) see if helps you